# How do I set the sort setting on devexpress group-panel on Angular

Tags: angular, devexpress

Below is the example from devexpress on grouping.
By default, the group-panel sorting is on asc order. Is there anyways to make it desc?
[image]

Is there any setting that I can refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Set the "SortOrder" property of the grouped column to "Descending"
The following is the case for setting in code.

```
gridView1.Columns["SomeFieldName"].SortOrder = DevExpress.Data.ColumnSortOrder.Descending;
```